# Power App Form Custom Size Not Showing Height And Width Entering Textboxes

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

When I customized my sharepoint form using power app I noticed one issue that for customizing the form size it doesn't showing width and height entering textboxes.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved for me when i change browser zooming.Before it was 100% now change to 90% then textboxes appeared.I think the issue is caused by my browser settings.
[image]